# Elastic search on both hibernate and mongodb domain classes together - Grails

Tags: hibernate, mongodb, grails, elasticsearch

I am having domain classes with both hibernate and mongodb mapping. Then I installed elastic search gorm plugin and mentioned

```
"elasticSearch.datastoreImpl = 'mongoDatastore'" in Config.groovy.
```

It works fine with mongodb domain classes. How do I apply elastic search on remaining hibernate domain classes ? If I put searchable = true, it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

Use Hibernate Search, and its new Elasticsearch integration:

- http://in.relation.to/2016/05/24/ElasticsearchintegrationReachesBeta1/

You might also want to consider Hibernate OGM to map the other entities to MongoDB:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-mongodb

As then you can use a consistent programming model, and integrate Hibernate Search with both of them.

(Disclaimer: I'm biased as I work on Hibernate fulltime, I actually didn't know about GORM being able to do a similar thing so I can't compare the two approaches).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution - Convert hibernate domain row to JSON and use native elastic-search call to add it to elastic-search database.